# Reading a CSV file from an unknown path, php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an php aplication that needs to import a CSV to mysql. But i only can import if the path is in the code. But i don't want it that way. I don't know were my cliente have the .CSV file.
Can you help me?
This is my code:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action="" method='post'onSubmit='getPath();'>
    <input type="file" name="file" /> 
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Importar'/>
</form>

<?php

$conexao = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
$bd = mysql_select_db ("wcfleet_demo"); 

if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) 
    {       


        $file = $_FILES ['file'] ['name'];

        $filepath="C:\\xampp\htdocs\wecreatefleet\\";
        $msg = $filepath."".$file; //bind
        $handle = fopen ($msg, "r");
        $i= 0;

        //$caminho = "C:\\xampp\htdocs\wecreatefleet\\teste.csv";   
        //$abraArq = fopen ($caminho, "r");

        if (!$handle) 
            {
                echo ("<p> Arquivo não encontrado! </p>");
            }
        else
            {
                while (($valores = fgetcsv ($handle, 100000, ";"))!== false) 
                {
                    $lines = file($msg);

                    if($i>=8)
                    {                       
                        $line = explode (';', $lines[$i]);          
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO via_verde (identificador, matricula, referencia, data_entrada, hora_entrada, entrada, data_saida, 
                                            hora_saida, saida, valor, valor_desconto, taxa_iva, operador, servico, data_pagamento, cartao_n) 
                                            VALUES ('$line[0]', '$line[1]', '$line[2]', '$line[3]', '$line[4]', '$line[5]', '$line[6]', '$line[7]', 
                                                    '$line[8]', '$line[9]', '$line[10]', '$line[11]', '$line[12]', '$line[13]', '$line[14]', '$line[15]')";     
                        mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error());                          
                    }
                    $i++;
                }   
                fclose ($handle);   
                mysql_close($conexao);
                echo "Processo finalizado.";        
            } 
    }
```

Comment: The `client` is uploading the csv file so at no point does your server get to know the location on their filesystem. You need to know, on the server's filesystem, where you can either move the uploaded file to or use the temp uploaded file as input to your script

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be able to use the filepath of the uploaded file as the source for `fopen` - `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` like this - though it is not tested. Unless you also need to save the uploaded csv file then there is not eveen a need to use `move_uploaded_file` as you would normally with file uploads.

The obligatory "do not use `mysql_*` functions" - they are deprecated and offer no protection against sql injection. Preferably use `mysqli` or `PDO` so that you can take advantage of `prepared statements`

```
<?php
    /* logic tests to ensure there is data present */
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_FILES['file'] ) ) {       

        /* assign the tmp_name of the uploaded file to a variable */
        $tmp  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        /* open a file handle on the temp file */
        $handle = fopen( $tmp, "r" );
        $i=0;

        if ( !$handle ) {
            echo "<p> Arquivo não encontrado! </p>";
        } else {
            /* only open db connection if there are no problems */
            $conexao = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ( mysql_error() );
            $bd = mysql_select_db ("wcfleet_demo"); 

            while ( $valores = fgetcsv( $handle, 100000, ";" )!== false ) {
                $lines = file( $msg );

                if( $i >= 8 ) {                       
                    $line = explode ( ';', $lines[$i]);          
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO via_verde (identificador, matricula, referencia, data_entrada, hora_entrada, entrada, data_saida, 
                                        hora_saida, saida, valor, valor_desconto, taxa_iva, operador, servico, data_pagamento, cartao_n) 
                                        VALUES ('$line[0]', '$line[1]', '$line[2]', '$line[3]', '$line[4]', '$line[5]', '$line[6]', '$line[7]', 
                                                '$line[8]', '$line[9]', '$line[10]', '$line[11]', '$line[12]', '$line[13]', '$line[14]', '$line[15]')";     
                    mysql_query( $sql ) or die ( mysql_error() );                          
                }
                $i++;
            }   
            fclose( $handle );   
            mysql_close( $conexao );
            /* delete the temp file */
            @unlink( $tmp );

            echo "Processo finalizado.";        
        }
    }
?>
```